# Column names missing from generator with pyodbc

Tags: python, generator, pyodbc

Im using Pyodbc to connect to sqlserver to get few rows. The select query I execute fetches almost 200,000 rows causing a memory issue.

To resolve this issue Im using a generator object, to fetch 5000 rows at any point in time..

The problem with this kind of execution is the generator object. I lose the data column names..

For example, if my table1 has column NAME, through normal exection I can access the result set as result.NAME

but I can't do the same with the generator object..It doesn't allow me to access through column names.

Any inputs will be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Cursor.fetchmany()`](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchmany) to process query result in batches returns a list of [`pyodbc.Row`](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Objects#Rows) objects, which allows reference by column name.

Take these examples of a SQL Server query that returns database names in batches of 5:

### Without generator

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
                            server='localhost', database='master',
                            trusted_connection='yes')
sql = 'select name from sys.databases'
cursor = connection.cursor().execute(sql)
while True:
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(5)
    if not rows:
        break
    for row in rows:
        print row.name
```

### With generator (modified from sample [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/137270-use-generators-for-fetching-large-db-record-sets/))

```
def rows(cursor, size=5):
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(size)
        if not rows:
            break
        for row in rows:
            yield row 

connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
                            server='localhost', database='master',
                            trusted_connection='yes')
sql = 'select name from sys.databases'
cursor = connection.cursor().execute(sql)
for row in rows(cursor):
    print row.name
```